# I would like to have numbers be replaced with their own summ in C language

Tags: c, arrays

I have to

```
1. create an array from N elements, which contains natural numbers
2. And then I have to replace each number in array with its own summ.
```

For example

```
23 -> 2 + 3 = 5;
2 -> 2;
845 -> 8 + 4 + 5 = 17
```

All this have to be created in C . Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: We will help if you try something,writing down whole code for you is what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getSum(int value){
    int sum = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (value > 0){
        sum += value % 10;
        value = value / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[] = { 23, 2, 845 };
    int i = 0;
    int sizeArr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
        arr[i] = getSum(arr[i]);
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

   int a[5]={11,23,485,561,452}, i=0;
   int tmp =i;
   int total = 0;

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     tmp = a[i];
    while(tmp>0)
    {
      total =  (tmp %10) + total;
      tmp = tmp /10;
    }
   a[i] = total;
   total =0;
 }
// print array
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
   printf("%d = %d\n",i,a[i]);
 }
  return 0;

 }

 //  Output
  0 = 2
  1 = 5
  2 = 17
  3 = 12
  4 = 11
```